# Warning: [deprecation] get(int,int) in CamcorderProfile has been deprecated issue

Tags: android, ios, flutter, camera, dependencies

I am using the https://pub.dev/packages/heart_bpm from the Flutter application and I get the following warning in the release version. The heart rate package is compatible with an old version of the camera package, so I cannot upgrade the old version. Will I have any problems with the release version or how can I solve this problem ?

```
...pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/camera_android-0.9.8+3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/camera/features/resolution/ResolutionFeature.java:154: warning: \[deprecation\] get(int,int) in CamcorderProfile has been deprecated
return CamcorderProfile.get(cameraId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
^
...pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/camera_android-0.9.8+3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/camera/features/resolution/ResolutionFeature.java:158: warning: \[deprecation\] get(int,int) in CamcorderProfile has been deprecated
return CamcorderProfile.get(cameraId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_2160P);
^
...pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/camera_android-0.9.8+3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/camera/features/resolution/ResolutionFeature.java:162: warning: \[deprecation\] get(int,int) in CamcorderProfile has been deprecated
return CamcorderProfile.get(cameraId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_1080P);
^
...pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/camera_android-0.9.8+3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/camera/features/resolution/ResolutionFeature.java:166: warning: \[deprecation\] get(int,int) in CamcorderProfile has been deprecated
return CamcorderProfile.get(cameraId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P);
^
...pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/camera_android-0.9.8+3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/camera/features/resolution/ResolutionFeature.java:170: warning: \[deprecation\] get(int,int) in CamcorderProfile has been deprecated
return CamcorderProfile.get(cameraId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P);
^
...pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/camera_android-0.9.8+3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/camera/features/resolution/ResolutionFeature.java:174: warning: \[deprecation\] get(int,int) in CamcorderProfile has been deprecated
return CamcorderProfile.get(cameraId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_QVGA);
^
...pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/camera_android-0.9.8+3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/camera/features/resolution/ResolutionFeature.java:178: warning: \[deprecation\] get(int,int) in CamcorderProfile has been deprecated
return CamcorderProfile.get(cameraId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
```

I don't want to override dependency.